# iOS view move down automatically after keyboard disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I had a iPad project, inside one of its view controllers, there are two TextFields inside a panel view (Views are build in Storyboard). What I would like to achieve is when any of those textfield become first responder (i.e. Keyboard Appears), the panel view will move up and if keyboard disappear it will move down to origin position.

Once I test move up, I found the view will automatically move back to origin position after keyboard disappear, but I didn't write any code to do that.

Code to move up:

```
- (void)moveUpTextFields {
    if ([self.emailTextField isFirstResponder] || [self.passwordTextField isFirstResponder]) {     
        CGRect frame = self.textFieldPanel.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= 50;
        self.textFieldPanel.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

So I would like to figure out how does that happen, and how should I achieve my goal (i.e. Move up if keyboard appear and back to original position)?

UPDATE:

To achieve my goals, it should use Keyboard Notification. Register these notifications in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

I did this in another project long time ago, just didn't remember it at the first place :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the weird behaviour is because when Keyboard Appear or Disappear, it will relayout view controller's sub views and trigger `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` and reposition view back to StoryBoard's position. If the view is created by code then this won't be a issue.

In addition to add notifications for KeyBoard, we also need to reposition the view in viewDidLayoutSubviews since the notification triggered before layout subviews.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height - self.textFieldPanel.frame.size.height - 5;

    CGRect frame = self.textFieldPanel.frame;
    panelViewYOffset = frame.origin.y - y;
    frame.origin.y -= panelViewYOffset;

    // Since it will layout subviews in viewDidLayout, why we set frame here?
    // I tried to move this line, turns out the panel will move up but the animation is gone
    // So this line will have a nice liner animation curve but I don't why, may be someone can explain it.
    self.textFieldPanel.frame = frame;    
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect frame = self.textFieldPanel.frame;
    frame.origin.y += panelViewYOffset;
    self.textFieldPanel.frame = frame;

    panelViewYOffset = 0;
}
```

In viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect frame = self.textFieldPanel.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= panelViewYOffset;

    self.textFieldPanel.frame = frame;
}
```

Like I mentioned, this approach only works for view from StoryBoard (Interface Builder), if `self.textFieldPanel` is created by code, then the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the keyboard events in the Notification Center, and lucky you, this is a functionality almost every app needs, so check this :)
https://github.com/aceontech/KBKeyboardHandler

It does exactly what you need but I prefer if you would understand how it behaves (registering for system notifications).

It's also available through cocoapods if you want

pod 'KBKeyboardHandler'

Comment: Oh, thanks, I forgot the listener which I did in another project one year ago.  Do you know why it moves down automatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by moving down automatically, so simply just register with the handler I gave you and implement the delegate method :) which will inform you when the keyboard appears or disappears so you could move your view up or down

Comment: Moving up and down is done like I said I did it in another project long time ago just didn't remember right away. The primary question in this post is to figure out some unexpected behaviour for, I assume, Text Field. The situation is I wrote code to move a view up after keyboard shows up. But when I dismiss the keyboard, the view go back to original position automatically. Since there is no code to move the view, it should stay the position after I moved up.

Comment: As I told you my friend, please go to the link, implement the delegate method and read the comment inside it, it shall solve your problem for both up and down in 3-4 lines of code

Comment: Implementing is one thing, understand what goes on under the hood is another thing. I've resolved it on my own.

Comment: It's simply listening to the keyboard messages that is raised by the NSNotificationCenter, when the keyboard appears, you move your view up and when it's hidden, you move it down, this library only provides a high level listener